# Name of quotient map followed by embedding

Tags: general-topology

Every continuous map $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ factors as $f=abc$ where $a$ is an embedding, $c$ is a quotient map and $b$ is a continuous bijection.

Is there a name for maps $f$ for which $b$ is a homeomorphism (ie, compositions of quotient maps and embeddings).

Comment: I do not know a special name. Perhaps one can invent a good name. A 'quotient embedding"?

Comment: @lee Seems a good choice in case it does not have already a name.